# Firebird database replication to ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, firebird, database-replication, mirroring

We have an firebird database connected to our access control system and then a separate web app that I developed for our time and attendance using sql server 2005 as the data source.

I wanted to use entity framework to connect to the firebird database to access data like users, transactions, sites, etc. As this method is very complicated getting the connection using firebird [.NET provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/) the other option I have is creating a sort of replication (Mirror) from the firebird database to sql server.

I have done this with a DTS previously (Selecting the data and then inserting it) and it worked fine but had many manual processes involved in getting the data and updates made it difficult.

Is there a simpler way to do this or any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to track what to replicate at the data level.  If you are only pushing it to the MS SQL database you could use a modified timestamp, or a record version field (create a generator, set a trigger to update the version field upon update) to reduce what you select.  Another popular option is to update a field to current_transaction, but if you do a restore you will start counting from 0.

If you are sending data both ways it gets more complicated -- you need to have conflict resolution.  You could look at something like the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992) which can use the methods above.